# How to set primary key starting value in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, database-migration

I want the primary key value of a table to start in this form in Laravel: **0001**.
Here's what I did:

```
$table->id()->startingValue(0001);
```

But when a record is created, instead of the "**0001**" pattern it returns **1**.

Yes, I know **0001** is the same thing as **1**.

Any idea how I could make it retain that pattern or flip it around?

Comment: You cannot do that, as the database is doing this and will always be `1`, `2`, `3`, etc... You cannot achieve this with a regular autoincremental ID... I do not recommend to manually assign it, why do you want `0001` instead of `1` ?

Comment: Just a thing of preference.

Comment: If it is pure preference, I strongly advise to remove that preference as it makes or changes nothing related to data. The default is `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, etc. and the database (auto incremental primary key) can only be that. So, before messing things up and giving you headaches, just stick with it. You can still have a `primary key` without `auto increment` and have it as `string`, because any `integer` value like `001` is always going to display `1`, but a `string` will stick to it `001`. I do not recommend in any way this as it is really bad because of indexing and more complex stuff...

Answer (score 0):

1. If you need to save it like that in de MySQL you'll need to use another type like string.
2. If it's only after db, laravel has [mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators).